# how to clear "only" the last db active record select query in codeigniter before firing an update call?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

How to clear the last select query in codeigniter before calling a db update call?.
currently, what's happening is, I have to do a select query, and then followed by an update query using the same db table. now the problem is, am getting this type of error where by it seem like the select * is being read in my update call

I tried using

```
$this->db->flush_cache() //didnt' helped
```

OR

```
$this->db->stop_cache() //didn't helped
```

OR

```
$this->db->free_result() //didn't helped
```

OR

```
$this->db->reset() // didn't helped
```

OR

```
$this->db->_reset_select()
```

so how ?

Comment: haven't you tried `$this->db->_reset_select();`

Comment: I tried it before calling my update call, and got this error `Call to protected method CI_DB_query_builder::_reset_select() from context `

Comment: oh its tagged CI3, that methods is for CI2

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#resetting-query-builder